# How to put a Google Adsense advert in an Infowindow created with Google Maps Api v3>

Tags: google-maps-api-3, adsense

I would like to put a Google Adsense advert into an InfoWindow, much like Google does with their Google Map Page. The Google Maps Javascript API v3/Developers Guide/Libraries/Adsense Library, does not cover this. It generally talks about putting Adsense adverts on top of the map - which works fine. I would like to be a bit more discrete than this. This library also talks about putting adverts in a separate div, but it does not seem to work for me. Any ideas out there? Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [**old V2 example**](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_adsense_infoWindow.html), which does it, (click the markers). I have not tried it with V3 but it should be the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty confident putting ads in the InfoWindow would violate the AdSense terms of service. This would require either preloading the ads, which would mean you'd be loading ads that aren't visible to the user (not allowed), or you would have to use JS to load the ads when the user clicks the icon on the map (not allowed), and may result in having more than 3 ads per page (not allowed).

Comment: I would give a try simply moving your banner between infowindows (not sure it would be allowed)